# regex to extract specific rule

Tags: regex, ruby

I have this string:

```
"/--shirt-blue-/2346985"
```

I need to detect '/--'
I solve using:

```
\/-{2}
```

But I need to detect if the string contains '/--' and the final contains '-/digit'

```
/--anything-/digit
```

How can I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following regex:

```
^\/--(?:[^-]*-){2}\/\d+$
```

Here is the [Online demo](https://rubular.com/r/7ytd5c1ouS8SRS) for above used regex in Ruby.

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above shown regex.

```
^\/--          ##Matching starting /(escaped it) followed by 2 dashes.
(?:[^-]*-){2}  ##In a non-capturing group matching everything till 1st occurrence of - including - and this match 2 times.
               ##So basically this will match till 2 dashes.
\/\d+$         ##Matching literal / followed by 1 or more digits at the end of the value.
```

Comment: the term shirt-blue can be more than 2. ex: "/--shirt-blue-long-navy-/2346985"

Comment: @jujajjjj, ok try `^\/--([^\/]*)\/\d+$` one once? https://rubular.com/r/tawrmsRA1UCyrK is the link online regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```rb
/\/--(.*?)-\/\d+\z/
```

See the [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/gkzqwIu7CiUDRc).

*Details*:

- `\/--` -  a `/--` string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `-\/` - a `-/` string
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\z` - end of string.

In [Ruby](https://ideone.com/L1V9Zt),

```rb
puts "/--shirt-blue-/2346985"[/\/--(.*?)-\/\d+\z/, 1]
```

shows `shirt-blue`.

Answer (score 0):

If there should be at least 1 char other than - in between:

```
^\/--(?:[^-]+-)+\/\d+\z
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\/` Match `/`
- `--` Match literally
- `(?:[^-]+-)+` Repeat 1+ times matching any char except `-` and then match `-`
- `\/\d+` Match `/` and 1+ digits
- `\z` End of string

See a [regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/DB1yQ1/1) and a [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/0xD9YMl9F8ICuh)